# Error Unknown column

Tags: django

Saludos tengo la siguiente relacion:

```
class Categoria(models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    porcentajeGanancia = models.FloatField(default=0)
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    estado = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

class Proveedor(models.Model):
    razon_social = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    ...
    categoria = models.ManyToManyField(Categoria)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.razon_social
```

en mi vista tengo:

```
def Proveedores(request):

    codigo_definida = settings.CODIGO_INICIAL_AUTOMATICO
    try:
        proveedor = Proveedor.objects.all().latest('id')
        codigo_existente = int(proveedor.codigo)
        codigo_nuevo = codigo_existente + 1
    except Proveedor.DoesNotExist:
        codigo_nuevo = codigo_definida

    template = loader.get_template('administrador/proveedores.html')
    context = {
        'proveedor_list': Proveedor.objects.all().order_by('razon_social'),
        'proveedor_form': ProveedorForm(),
        'categoria_list': Categoria.objects.all(),
        'codigo_nuevo':str(codigo_nuevo).zfill(7)
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

el error que genera:

> "Unknown column 'proveedores_proveedor.categoria_id' in 'field list'"

esto sucedio a raiz de que hice el cambio en el model donde un Proveedor puede pertenecer a multiples categorias.
Antes del cambio tenia un proveedor una categoria usaba "ForeingKey".

Quiza alguna sugerencia de como solucionar este inconveniente gracias de antemano.